# Would a constructive proof that intuitionstic ZF has a nonconstructive model be a problem for the intuitionist?

Tags: set-theory, foundations, constructive-mathematics, intuitionistic-logic

It is my understanding it is provable in ZFC+zero sharp that intuitionistic ZF has a nonconstructive model.

(Here I am assuming the existence of zero sharp only to guarantee that ZFC has a nonconstructive model, which I guess most people probably believe)

I cannot find any proof online and am not in a place to attempt to prove this myself, and so I don't know if there is a constructive proof of this (constructive in a manner that would satisfy the intuitionist).

Assuming there is, would this be a problem for the intuitionist?

My thought is this: if it can be constructively proved that the intuitionists foundational theory is 'just as true' in a nonconstructive ontology, the intuitionist has in no way 'guaranteed' that their universe is constructive.

Comment: What is a "nonconstructive model"? (Note that "constructive" in the sense of intuitionistic logic is very different from "constructible" in the sense of classical set theory. $0^\sharp$ is tightly connected with the latter, but has nothing to do as far as I'm aware with the former.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber by "nonconstructive model" I mean a model which contains sets which cannot be described in terms of simpler sets. I assume that the intuitionist would not think such sets exist. Forgive me if my rambling question is predicated on a misunderstanding--I am but a lowly philosophy undergrad attempting to understand some philosophy of maths.

Comment: Can there be a constructive proof of the existence of a nonconstructive anything? Doesn't a constructive proof of an existential statement $(\exists x)\dots x\dots$ require constructing a suitable $x$?

Comment: @AndreasBlass my thought was this: the nonconstructive model is one which contains sets which cannot be described in terms of simpler sets, but this fact alone would not make the nonconstructive model itself unable to be constructed. I admit this thought might just be wrong!

Comment: Some things worth pointing out: $\mathsf{Set}$ satisfies excluded middle iff the metalogic does, $\mathsf{FinSet}$ satisfies excluded middle *whatsoever*, $\mathsf{Sh}(\mathbb R)$ doesn't satisfy excluded middle *whatsoever*.

Answer (score 3):

I’m not exactly sure what “nonconstructive model” means in this context. In fact, when one is discussing constructive theories, one must typically adopt a broader class of models than the class classical logicians consider.

That said, it is well-known that IZF and ZF are equiconsistent. This is not too surprising, as there are many other constructive theories that are equiconsistent with a classical counterpart, such as Heyting Arithmetic and Peano Arithmetic. I personally don’t think this says too much about which one is “true” or “correct”, but that’s more of a philosophical question. The obvious and relevant facts are (1) one can prove quite a few nice things using classical logic that can’t be proved constructively, and (2) there are a lot of interesting and useful models of constructive mathematics which aren’t models of classical mathematics.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I think my original question is probably based on a misunderstanding. On your point (2), do you mean things like models of intuitionistic real analysis?

Comment: @shipwaymg Yes, one useful class of models is models of Brouwer-style intuitionist analysis. There are quite a few others.